# What causes MS VB Run-time Error -2147417848 (80010108) in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I have a macro which runs fine on my machine but when I try to run it on another machine it gives the following error.

Microsoft Visual Basic

Run-time Error -2147417848 (80010108)
Automation Error
The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the error is caused by 'Freeze Panes'. If you are in the sliding part of the panel you get the crash, if you are in the frozen bit everything works fine.
The solution is: first change the active cell to a cell in the frozen pane, e.g. **Range("A1").Activate**

Comment: I also received this error, and this discussion gave me the clue to fix it. I'm setting up automation of Excel from VBA in Access (both 2007). I was using Workbooks.Add() and then trying to import a CSV file to Sheet1 with ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=filename, Destination:=Range("$A$1")), and then would receive the exact error mentioned above. I read this thread and stuck in Range("A1").Activate appropriately, and it fixed the problem. It would seem that if cell A1 is not explicitly active, QueryTable cannot import to it. Perhaps it does not become active until first displayed on screen?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21961) is a possible solution. I haven't encountered the error myself so I'm not sure so...

Also, more detail would be helpful, what is the code surround the line where it errors? What is the code doing? Are both machines running the same version of Windows and Excel?